# if $a'b+cd'=0$, then prove that $ab+c'(a'+d')=ab+bd+b'd'+a'c'd$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $a'b+cd'=0$, then prove that $$ab+c'(a'+d')=ab+bd+b'd'+a'c'd$$

I would like to know how to solve this expression, not able to make any headway. I have tried canonical form expansion and reduction but the terms in the if condition does not match and also not able to generate the terms in the given expression.

Comment: What is  the symbol $'$?

Comment: Hi! And welcome to MSE. I think that you are missing some relations. If you start considering $ab+c'(a'+d')$, you can not make appear $d$, since your unique relation $a'b+cd'=0$ does not contain any $d$, for example. Hence, I guess you have some missing relations. It could be between those $a,b,c,d$ and their respective $a',b',c',d'$. Let us know. Edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

A truth table shows that left-hand-side and righ-hand-side are in fact equivalent if the constraint is fulfilled (indicated by background color):

[image]